# How to export Visual Studio 2010 UML Modeling Diagrams

Tags: visual-studio, uml, visual-studio-2010

I recently created a very nice UML Class diagram inside Visual Studio 2010 (b2). The tools worked like a charm and I was able to model a rather complex domain within minutes.

However, I cannot find any way to export my diagram as an image (PNG/JPEG/etc.).

Does the modelling features in VS2010 support exporting diagrams as images? If so - how do I do it?

Print src is NOT the answer.

**Edit:** Found one way to export... Go to File > Print and select Adobe PDF

**Edit 2:** Found another, slightly more elegant, way to export. In the diagram editor: Select all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>), Copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>), Go to your favourite image editor (paint works fine) and Paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>). Voila!

Comment: Solution 2 works best, thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The VS 2010 Ultimate RC documentation has more info about exporting the UML diagrams as images: [How to: Save Images of Diagrams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554948%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

We now have a topic in the documention about how to do this programmatically:

[How to: Export UML Diagrams to Image Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff469815.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

See also Cameron Skinner's blog post [*Save a diagram to Image File*](http://blogs.msdn.com/camerons/archive/2010/03/08/save-a-diagram-to-image-file.aspx)

This describes how to create a context menu option in VS which will allow you to export the diagram as an image.