# How do I export a DBML diagram from Visual Studio into an image?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql

I have a very pretty DBML diagram that I would like to preserve in our Design Documents. How do I get an image showing all of the tables in one go?

I found [How to export Visual Studio 2010 UML Modeling Diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686767/how-to-export-visual-studio-2010-uml-modeling-diagrams) but the slightly elegant solution of copying all the items and pasting them into an image editor doesn't work in this case.

Am I stuck with Print Screen and manually stitching the images together?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could print to the Microsoft Document Image Writer. That'll create a TIFF for you.

For those unaware, it's a virtual printer included in Microsoft Office Professional allowing documents to be saved in TIFF.

Answer (score 1):

first Install adobe acrobat then inside visual studio click on print preview and then click print you should print as a pdf file .

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered printing the .dbml to a PDF document?

That might alleviate some concerns around stitching your own print-screens together yourself. If you specify the page size as 'big as you can' in the print dialog, you could avoid the multi-page problems.

This of course wouldn't generate an image, but you could then use/view this document to create a proper digital image as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Visual Studio does not allow save as image a dbml diagram. In my case I printed (Ctr + P) and saved as a PDF document. Then I used a site like [this](https://www.freepdfconvert.com/pdf-image), which allows convert PDF to Image.